# proving that Laurent coefficients are $0$ for $n<0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let the function $f$ be defined and holomorphic in the punctured disc $D'(a,r)$ and let ${c_n}$ be the Laurent coefficients of $f$ at $a$. Assume that $f$ is bounded on $D'(a,r)$.

Use the Estimation Theorem to show that $c_n=0$ for $n<0$.

I really can't see how to link the estimation theorem to proving this, so could anyone help me see the link here

Answer (score 1):

The Laurent coefficients have the integral representation

$$c_n = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\lvert z-a\rvert = \rho} \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}\,dz$$

for an arbitrary $\rho \in (0,r)$. For $n < 0$, let $\rho \to 0$ in the estimation lemma.